# Encoding javascript url to pass #(hashtag)

Tags: javascript, php

I'm passing a URL to a PHP file in which to change some colors etc. One of the colors is `#ccc` and is passed up as `&background=#ccc` which breaks my PHP file (It stops my `$_GET` parameters at that hashtag, everything after that is not passed along)

I've tried encoding my url as `encodeURIComponent(url)` which also encodes my ? and & I use for my $_GET string. When using `encodeURI()` the hashtag isn't encoded at all.

Any ideas how to pass all my vars to my PHP file so I can read them there?

**Please note** that it's a stylesheet href. I can't/won't use jQuery's `$.get()` method but just parse a  tag and append it in my  as such:

```
<link href="http://localhost:8888/test.php/layout.scss?primarycolor=hotpink&secondarycolor=white&background=#ccc&textcolor=black&linkcolor=black&font=Futura&" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="custom-style">
```

Comment: cant you just pass background=ccc and in code behind add hashtag?

Comment: yeah, use 'ccc' and provide hashtag afterwards. people always use too complicated solutions.

Comment: Except for the fact that people can pass "black" aswell. Which would convert to "#black" then. It would be a lot more complicated to outrule a lot of things that DON'T need a hashtag ;)

Comment: hmmm.. but still they can pass background=#black so whats different? :)

Comment: use `encodeURIComponent` which will convert `#` to %23 but in your PHP you will get it as `#`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`encodeURIComponent` is correct, but you only want to use it on the `#ccc` bit. If you are doing it by hand (as in, hardcoding in the `<link>` tag), then use `%23` instead of `#`.

Comment: That's how I fixed it now; I was hoping there would be a sexier way of handling it, though. But seeing the answers thus far I don't think there is.

Answer (score 1):

Hash tags are not passed to the server, so that's why they're breaking your script. As for encoding, if encodeURIComponent() works, you'll probably have to encode each value in the URL. Alternatively, you can just replace the # symbol in your url with %23 using a simple string replace.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a proprietary encoding system. For example, saying that "#" is equal to "!-!" for example.

Then in your server-side PHP code you can run a `str_replace("!-!", "#", $getVar)` statement to use the colour code correctly. Not ideal however.

Also, try: `htmlentities` and `html_entity_decode`: http://php.net/htmlentities